# Having trouble implementing a simple arithmatic program in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to implement the following program in assembly:

```
int number;
printf("\n%s","Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d",&number);
number=7-number*3;
printf("\n%s%d\n\n","The integer is: ",number);
```

So far my attempt is this:

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
scanf PROTO arg2:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
    .data
in1fmt byte "%d",0
msg1fmt byte 0Ah,"%s",0
msg1 byte "Enter an integer: ",0
msg2fmt byte 0Ah,"%s%d",0Ah,0Ah,0
msg2 byte "The integer is: ",0
number sdword ?
    .code
main proc
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1
    INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR number
    mov eax, number
    mov ebx, 3
    imul ebx
    mov number, eax
    mov eax, 7
    sub eax, number
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg2fmt, ADDR msg2, eax
    ret
main endp
    end
```

The first problem seems to be that eax is not stored in number. When I print out the value of number after assining eax into number, it outputs the value as 21 for an input of 30. eax is 90, yet after moving eax into number number is 21.

I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I just can't see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? This doesn't look like the complete code to me.

Comment: @JesusRamos I minimized it as I thought it was good on this site to reduce code as much as possible. I have added my entire program in the question now.

Comment: It usually is but assembly is a tricky thing :P

Comment: How about running this program in a debugger and examining the registers and variables after each instruction in this subroutine? That would tell you where you're messing things up.

Comment: @Alex I would not have thought it would be necessary for such a simple thing. Surely with a program this small any logic error should be apparent?

Answer (score 0):

```
enterMsg db 'Enter an integer: ',0
resultMsg db 'The integer is: %d\r\n',0    ; yep, I refactored this one

stringPattern db '%s',0

; ...


proc main
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4

    lea eax,[ds:enterMsg]
    push eax
    lea eax,[ds:stringPattern]
    push eax
    call printf    ; printf("%s", enterMsg); // btw, why?
    add esp,8


    lea eax,[ebp - 4]
    push eax
    lea eax,[ds:intPattern]
    push eax
    call scanf     ; scanf("%d", &number);
    add esp,8

    mov eax,[dword ptr ss:ebp - 4]
    push eax
    call calculate    ; number = calculate(number);
    add esp,4
    mov [dword ptr ss:ebp - 4],eax

    lea eax,[ebp - 4]
    push eax
    lea eax,[ds:resultMsg]
    push eax
    call printf    ; printf(resultMsg, number);
    add esp,8

    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
endp main


; number=7-number*3;
proc calculate
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    push ebx

    ; not considering integer overflow for now
    mov eax,[dword ptr ss:ebp + 8]
    mov ebx,3
    imul ebx
    neg eax
    add eax,7

    pop ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
endp calculate
```

C programs are fairly simple to translate into ASM.
With *cdecl* calling convention, you push the arguments of a subroutine from right to left, invoke the subroutine, and get your return value in `eax` (if any; or ST0 for float). Then you clean up the stack and that's it.

The problem I think is you push the value of the result on the stack rather than a pointer to it. Not sure though; I haven't used C rtl in ASM for quite some time